# BaseAdapter, getView is not called despite notifyDataSetChanged() being called

Tags: android, baseadapter

Although every time I udpated the data, I called notifyDataSetChanged(), function getView() was never called.
Here is my class, any tip? Thanks

```
public class TripGroupAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = LogUtils.makeTag(TripGroupAdapter.class);

    private Context mContext;

    private List<TripGroup> mGroups;

    private Query mQuery;



    public TripGroupAdapter(final Context context, final List<TripGroup> groups, Query query) {
        mContext = context;
        mGroups = groups;
        mQuery = query;
    }

    public void setGroups(final List<TripGroup> groups) {
        mGroups = groups;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public void addGroup(TripGroup group) {
        if(mGroups == null)
            mGroups = new LinkedList<TripGroup>();

        mGroups.add(group);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mGroups == null ? 0 : mGroups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public TripGroup getItem(final int position) {
        if(getCount() == 0 || position < 0 || position >= getCount())
            return null;
        else
            return mGroups.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        TripGroup group = getItem(position);

        if(group == null)
            return -1;
        else
            return group.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = new TripListItemView(mContext);
        }

        TripListItemView tripView = (TripListItemView) convertView;
        tripView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_trip_result_card);
        tripView.set(mGroups.get(position), mQuery, mCache);

        return tripView;
    }

    public void setQuery(final Query query) {
        mQuery = query;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {

        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

Comment: Do you actually set the adapter to the listview ? (or other content displayer)

Comment: @GrIsHu of course, that's why I know getView is not called. I set a breakpoint inside notifyDataSetChanged() and it did jump in there.

Comment: @Geoffroy yes I did. I just posted most relevant code here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the reason, post here for those having the same problem. I use Otto bus to broadcast and the function that catches the broadcast and update the underlying data `setGroups` **didn't run on uiThread**. So in that function, I had to force it, like this:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mTripGroupAdapter.setGroups(tripGroupsList);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the case in this question, but another possibility that `getView` is not called after `notifyDataSetChanged`, make sure `BaseAdapter` methods

```
registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) 
unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer)
```

are not overridden.